# How Do I extract "Results" from this JSON file and using NumPy do calculations on it?

Tags: python, arrays, json, numpy, boto3

I am new at Python, only just recently started, I am using Python Boto3,

here is my JSON file:

```
   Student = [{"Student_ID": 1,
    "Name":"Erik",
    "ExamSubject": "English",
    "Result": "72.3",
    "ExamDate": "9/12/2020",
    "Gender": "M"},



   {"Student_ID": 2,
    "Name":"Daniel",
    "ExamSubject": "English",
    "Result": "71",
    "ExamDate": "9/12/2020",
    "Gender": "M"},


   {"Student_ID": 3,
    "Name":"Michael",
    "ExamSubject": "English",
    "Result": "62",
    "ExamDate": "9/12/2020",
    "Gender": "M"}

    ]


    print(Student)
```

I need to extract "Results" from this JSON file and make it into an Array and do the following Calculations;

Max, Min, Mean average, Standard Deviation:

```
     x = np.array([0]) 
     max_x = x.max() #Maximum value of test data 
     min_x = x.min() #Minimum value of test data 
     mean_x = x.mean() #Mean average of test data 
     std_x = x.std() #Standard deviation of test data
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a list comprehension:

```
x = np.array([s['Result'] for s in Student]).astype(float)

# other operations
x.min(), x.max()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
results = [float(student["Result"]) for student in students]
x = np.array(results)
```

I've also renamed `Student` to `students` to better describe what is is.